# Prevent step into static library code

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I have successfully created static library and using it,

But could not find method / solution that prevent user to step into static library code.

All my .m files are embedded in .a file,

**Steps to see static library implementation is as follow:**

1. User import static library and header file in his project.
2. Import header file and call any method from static library file.
3. Put a breakpoint at line, from where he call static library function.
4. Whenever code reaches that breakpoint, He click on step Into button.

By following above steps He/She can get into my implementation file.

I want to hide my implementation from user at any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't really. What you're seeing is Xcode finding the source files elsewhere on your computer.  If you move them to another computer you won't see them any more.  For that matter if you just move the source files on your computer you won't.